# Neo4j - Cypher - images gallery system with parents and child

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j with a mysql background, I'm trying to convert an old mysql 
image gallery system to a Neo4j graph database, the schema that I came with is represented in the graph below :

[image: neo4j graph]

_ There is user nodes with tow relation types :

- Posted : `(:User)-[:POSTED]->(:Post)`
- Has Avatar : `(:User)-[:HAS_AVATAR]->(:Image)`

_ Post nodes with tow relation types :

- Has Child for the parent gallery post : `(:Post)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(:Post)`
- Has image for the gallery child posts : `(:Post)-[:HAS_IMAGE]->(:Image)`

_ finaly image nodes.

This is a simplified version actually each post (the parent and the child) can have a link or a video instead of an image and can be commented or liked by users.

To get all the data that I need from the graph I'm using this cypher query:

```
MATCH (p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(u:User) WHERE NOT (p)<-[:HAS_CHILD]-(:Post)
MATCH (u)-[:HAS_AVATAR]->(ua:Image)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c:Post)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:HAS_IMAGE]-(i:Image)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS_IMAGE]-(ci:Image)
RETURN
[p._id, [u.username, ua._id], i._id, c._id, ci._id] as post
```

It end up with a result like this :

[image]

Again, I'm keeping this query simple, for the sake of clarity, each image has an id, a width and a height, each child post can have a different user from its parent and each post has it's own comments and likes from different users the real result is far bigger than this one.

Right now I have to deal with many `lodash/union`, to get rid of all the duplicate result (post ids, usernames ...)

My question is, am I doing it right? Is there a better approach? I'm actually reading about `MERGE` and trying poorly to implement it.

So I'm referring to you guys and your expertise for any advice, especially if it can get all the union functions inside of the cypher query.

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you want your result to be structured?

Comment: I'm working just fine with the actual result, as it is my first attempt with neo4j, i'm just asking if i'm doing any thing wrong or if the query can be improved

Comment: You may want to consider if you want to collect any results along the way. For example, would you like the results structured such that each line consists of the parent post, user id and and avatar id, and the collection of child posts and images? That way all of the child posts would be aggregated into the row with the parent post. Usually aggregation is the way you reduce repetition in the results.

Comment: So, as @InverseFalcon indicates, you can restructure your output in various ways, probably using [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/). Since you are the one consuming the results, you have to decide first how you want your result to be structured. Afterwards, you can figure out how to write your query to get that structure.

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses ... that's exactly what I want and that's what the query return, parent and child in the same rows to get the minimum rows possible ... like I said I'm new to neo4j and I learned everything alone by my self, so I was worrying to get the wrong path, especially with all those (optional match)  ... beside the data structure, as you didn't mention any other issue I can guess that the query is OK ... your reassuring me and I thank you for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you want to use aggregation to collect results together and minimize the number of rows and repetition of elements in the results.

From your query, it looks like you may have been trying to do this already by outputting lists. Keep in mind that there is a difference between putting some of your results into lists (which just changes the structure of results per row) vs using `collect()` or other approaches which do aggregation, as that takes results from multiple rows and collects them together into a single row (per grouping key), so you end up with fewer rows total.

Here's your query with changes to collect the child posts per parent post:

```
MATCH (p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(u:User) 
WHERE NOT (p)<-[:HAS_CHILD]-() 
// the above uses the degree of those relationships on the node, more efficient
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c:Post) // potentially multiple children
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS_IMAGE]-(ci:Image) // assume at most 1 image per child post
WITH p, u, collect(c {._id, image:ci._id}) as children
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:HAS_IMAGE]-(i:Image) // assume at most 1 image per post
WITH p, u, children, i
MATCH (u)-[:HAS_AVATAR]->(ua:Image) // assume at most 1 avatar per user
RETURN p {._id, image:i._id, children} as post, u {.username, avatar:ua._id} as user
```

This uses [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection) to project out properties from a map (or in this case, properties from a node) and add in our own properties to the map from other matched elements.

Alternately, if you wanted to do something similar, but in addition collect posts per user, you could do something like this:

```
MATCH (p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(u:User) 
WHERE NOT (p)<-[:HAS_CHILD]-() 
// the above uses the degree of those relationships on the node, more efficient
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c:Post) // potentially multiple children
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS_IMAGE]-(ci:Image) // assume at most 1 image per child post
WITH u, p, collect(c {._id, image:ci._id}) as children
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:HAS_IMAGE]-(i:Image) // assume at most 1 image per post
WITH u, collect(p {._id, image:i._id, children}) as posts
MATCH (u)-[:HAS_AVATAR]->(ua:Image) // assume at most 1 avatar per user
RETURN u {.username, avatar:ua._id} as user, posts
```

Comment: Work amazingly  well, far better then what I expected ... thank you very much sire ... I'll need some time to process all the magic you did here